# How can each OpenStack Swift object-storage container be set up with a different password/key in a standard way?

Tags: password, openstack, containers, object-storage, swift

I'd like to have many storage buckets, each with its own password or key for read & write access for use by end users.

Some options I've discovered:

1. [ACLs](https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/overview_acl.html): These work on a per-OpenStack-user basis.  I don't think it makes sense to create a new OpenStack user for each end user.
2. [Application credentials](https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/latest/user/application_credentials.html): These can't be set on a per-container basis, but rather on a class of operations.  So you can restrict to containers, but that's for *all* containers, not a specific one.

Cloud-A [announced Container Specific API Keys](https://www.clouda.ca/blog/tech/dash/bulk-storage-container-api-keys-2/) ([documented elsewhere](http://docs.clouda.ca/bulk-storage/container-keys)), but this appears to be non-standard.  I'd like something that will be compatible with upstream OpenStack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, it seems as though this isn't possible currently.  However, there are plans to fix this eventually:

- [Add Fine Grained Restrictions to Application Credentials](https://specs.openstack.org/openstack/keystone-specs/specs/keystone/train/capabilities-app-creds.html) (the specs)
- [Identity (keystone): White List Extension for Application Credentials](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/keystone/+spec/whitelist-extension-for-app-creds) (the blueprints)